# ASP.NET MVC C# - MYSQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, model-view-controller

I am new to ASP.NET. I want to develop a system to enable users login and view their own data based on what I have already in my SQL database. Also, how can I change that default MVC template to use mySQL database especially when I register a user

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to MySql.Data by typing the following into the Package Manager Console.

> Install-Package MySql.Data

Then you can set up queries agains your MySQL by building the connection string and SQL commands, for example...

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conn_string.Server = "myserver.com";
conn_string.UserID = "userid";
conn_string.Password = "password";
conn_string.Database = "database";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString()))
using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
      cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table1";
      conn.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, Let me try do so!